# Слово-фантом ТИПО

Tags: словообразование, жаргон

> У него нос на маске и крылья. Типо журавль. Все забыли уже, а он ещё помнит… [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]
>
> Белая, Джесси, дочь машиниста на паровом катере «Порт Саид», а чёрная, Типо, дочь рулевого на том же катере. [Е.Л. Шварц. Приключения мухи // «Чиж», 1930]
>
> Типо крайне был рад, и водил посланника смотреть озеро Аципони. [Иакинф (Бичурин). Собрание сведений о народах, обитавших в Средней Азии в древние времена (1851)]

Собственно на Пелевине (у Шварца и Иакинфа оно — имя) поиск этого слова в литературных источниках, не успев начаться, закончился. Два случая в газетном корпусе не в счёт.

Вопрос такой: почему слово, как говорят, разговорное, на слух и по смыслу (как я представляю) не отличающееся от «типа», лишь на бумаге его искажающее, стало популярным на форумах?

(На украинском прозвучало акцентировано. Может быть корни явления надо искать там? На канале NewsOne-онлайн слышал отчётливое и продолжительное окончание на паузе, как перед перечислением: «*Это абсолютно развязывает руки всем активистам типо... пана Стерненко, не знаю... and Company*».)

Comment: Вы мне напомнили: [Типа такой vs типа такого](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/20465/%d0%a2%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-vs-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be), был похожий вопрос на англоязычном ресурсе.